# wbar recognised as dock by openbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, openbox

I'm debian user. I have got tint2 dock on the top and this is recognized by openbox. I mean when new window appears it is under tint2. I have installed wbar as well. Here's the problem. I don't want to allow apps to cross boarder of wbar even in maximized mode. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with tint2 or wbar specifically, but in openbox there is an option (default context menu -> ObConf -> Margins ) that allows you to prevent windows from getting closer than X pixels from one or more sides of the screen, even when maximized. Does this option work for you with those two programs?